# Unable to initialize model in Swift

Tags: swift

I am looking to have a data model that is created by the user in the main View Controller and then passed into other view controllers via prepareForSegue.

However in my View Controller I am unable to use the model and I get errors for unwrapped optional values.

I have :

```
Class Collection: NSObject {
   var id: String!
   var image: String!
   var apples: Int?
   var oranges: Int?
   var lemons: Int?
}

init(id: String, image: String, apples: Int, oranges: Int, lemons: Int) {
    super.init()
    self.id = id
    self.photo = photo
    self.apples = apples
    self.oranges = oranges
    self.lemons = lemons
}
```

View Controller:

```
var collection: Collection!
...
    // if user selects a number ..
    self.collection.oranges = usersSelection
    self.collection.apples = usersSelection
    etc
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please? 
Thank you!

Comment: Did you call the initializer of `Collection`?

Comment: In the View Controller yes. 
If I call 
var collection = Collection(id: "", photo: "", apples: 0, oranges: 0, lemons: 0) 
it works but I am unable to access the properties to change them with dot notation .

Comment: Why an `NSObject` subclass? You could just use a struct.

Answer (score 0):

Define your model class like this:

```
class Collection: NSObject {
    var id: String!
    var image: String!
    var apples: Int?
    var oranges: Int?
    var lemons: Int?

    init(id: String, image: String, apples: Int?, oranges: Int?, lemons: Int?) {

        super.init()
        self.id = id
        self.image = image

        if let _ = apples{
            self.apples = apples
        }
        if let _ = oranges{
            self.oranges = oranges
        }
        if let _ = lemons{
            self.lemons = lemons
        }

    }

}
```

Then implement in your ViewController like this:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var collection: Collection!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        collection = Collection(id: "user selection", image: "useselection", apples: nil, oranges: nil, lemons: nil)
//      collection.image =
//      colection.oranges =
//      ........

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried that and I get an error "Nil is not compatible with argument type Int"

Comment: But before post the answer I have checked my code in playground. Could you share your errors?

Comment: For your suggestion,  my error is that Nil is not compatible with expected argument type "int"

Comment: Also, when I try to cast the collection option type, I get an error saying nil was unexpectedly found while unwrapping an optional value. However in my App the Optional variables are not needed in every instance

Comment: Please read about how unwrap optional value. There is no problem in code. You try on forcefully unwrap optional value and  then throw the error.

Comment: You are correct. Simply when initializing the model class I had to use 

self.collection!.apples = usersSelection.

Thank you for the help! Really appreciate it :-)